# Google Chrome won't let me place breakpoints

Tags: javascript, debugging, json, google-chrome

I've been using Google Chrome to debug my javascript, but then all of a sudden I can no longer place breakpoints. I click on the line number, where I previously clicked to add a breakpoint, but no breakpoint will be added. Sometimes if I click very fast, like a madman, I can see it trying to add breakpoints, but it won't stick.

The only thing I changed was adding JSONView. I uninstalled that, but still can't add breakpoints.

Does anyone have any idea?

An edit:
I can place breakpoints on other pages, like StackOverflow, just not the one I'm developing running on localhost.

Comment: I've had problems when working on local files.  Could you try hosting it on a webserver?  I do all of my work on my local server (connectd on my local lan) with no open ports to the outside world and I haven't had any problems.  You could just install Apache locally.

Comment: I know it doesn't solve the problem, but you could use the debugger js statement instead

Comment: We discovered the following bizarre problem: **1)** Chrome refuses to set runtime breakpoints in FileA.js. **2)** We get around this by putting `debugger;` statements in that file instead. **3)** Under some additional circumstances, Chrome starts *ignoring any code* in the transaction callbacks in the Web SQL API (http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#asynchronous-database-api) while stepping through code. Apparently, when Chrome doesn't want you setting breakpoints in a particular code file, it really means it.

Comment: I have strange behavior sometimes as, still, after a few years. I shut down and restart Chrome and that usually helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bug was fixed yesterday (February 3) with the introduction of a new api for managing JavaScript breakpoints: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69988

I downloaded the most recent Chromium nightly from http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/ and was able to successfully set breakpoints in JavaScript, which I had been unable to do using the current stable/beta/dev builds of Chrome.

Hopefully this fix will be incorporated into the next releases of Chrome. Until then, adding `debugger;` statements to your code is a decent workaround for setting breakpoints.

Comment: The Chrome Canary build is a quick and easy way to get the fixed version. It runs alongside your current Chrome installation and autoupdates very frequently (windows only). http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs

Answer (score 17):

No it's not fixed. The Chrome debugger has done this for as long as I can remember. Just close and reopen the debugger and it usually comes right again. Sometimes you may need to try several times for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This will also happen when trying to set a breakpoint on unreachable code.  If starting up a debugger in a new chrome process continues to cause problems, make sure there's no errant breaks or returns etc. prior to the breakpoint.

eg:

```
var foo = 'bar';
return foo;

foo = 'baz';
debugger
```

^^^ statements after return in above example will not be reached, chrome will rightly refuse to honor debugger commands or set breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Check your JS code! Got the error too on Chrome (and Firefox) and the error was a method named exactly like another.